# Access a document in SharePoint library from Azure functions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pdf, flow, azure-functions

I am relatively new in Microsoft's world. I started on it three months ago and I have a doubt about the connection between SharePoint online (specifically, with libraries and lists), Microsoft Flow and Azure functions.

What I am doing is:

1. I insert a PDF file inside a SharePoint online library.
2. A Flow starts and I send the CONTENT of that PDF file (**a text one, not an image that needs OCR treatment**) to an Azure function.
3. I try to read that content but it's impossible for me.
4. And finally, send specific parts of the content to the FLOW and then to another SharePoint online list.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to pass and read the content of a PDF file to an Azure functions? And, if it's possible, what do you recommend me to use (e.g. C# with X library, or JavaScript with X module)
2. Is there any other options to do what I want to do? I think that it could be better if I pass the **SharePoint online path** of the PDF file to Azure functions and then start to work with the path (because, presumably, the Azure function knows that, in that path, there is a PDF file) but I don't know if I could do that.
   Obviously, if it possible, can you recommend me anything?

That's all.

Thank you so much and sorry for my English.

Best regards,

Carlos.