# SharePoint Online Documentation

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, documentation

As I mentioned in my first question in this site ([Access a document in SharePoint library from Azure functions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267240/access-a-document-in-sharepoint-library-from-azure-functions)), I am new in Microsoft's world. In this sense, I am going to work with SharePoint Online (and React + SharePoint Framework)

Even though I have been looking for documentation, I want to ask here if anyone can recommend me **specific handbooks, YouTube channels** - I already know about the SharePoint PnP Community, i.e or anything like that to improve my knowledge about these subjects.

That's all. Thank you so much!

Best regards,

Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Framework, you can first check the official doc [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview). It will always be a good starting point. And you can check samples and tutorial [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts)

Answer (score 0):

Find below references for learning Development using SharePoint Framework:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) - Official documentation by Microsoft.
2. [SharePoint Developer Community - PnP](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_mKdhw-V6CeCM7gTo_Iy7w) - YouTube Channel
3. [SharePoint Framework Release Notes](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki#release-notes) - GitHub
4. [SharePoint Framework WebPart Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts) - GitHub
5. [SharePoint Framework Extension Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions) - GitHub
6. [Visual Studio extension for SharePoint Framework projects](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-vs-extension)

Comment: Does this answers your question? If Yes then please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will get closed and removed from Unanswered questions.